# Automatic & Scheduled import mdb in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, ssis

I have a .bat file that download via ftp a file xyz.mdb in a known folder.

This access db has tables with names which may vary every month.

I need, via a scheduled job to launch the bat file and then import xyz.mdb in SQL Server in a specific database (I can drop and recreate it).

Any suggestions? I'm not very good with ssis.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your BAT file, use WinSCP or similar for FTP download.  You can call it using an Execute Process Task and control your process flow based on success or failure. When it succeeds, then add a For Each Loop container and point it at the "known folder", assigning each file name to a Variable.  Then within the loop you can add a Data Flow Task that reads from each Access DB.

The first tricky part is the Connection definition.  You need to use an expression to generate the Connection string.  Start from one you generate manually, then rebuild it in an expression, substituting your Variable for the file name.

Second tricky part is the Connection stack. The Access Database Engine 2010 gives you OLE DB on 64 bit, but bizarrely it only works in one flavor at a time, 64 bit or 32 bit.  This causes a lot of confusion as even on a 64 bit machine, BIDS is always 32 bit.

I've started using the ODBC Drivers instead.  Microsoft have already stated that OLE DB will be deprecated in the future and ODBC is the way to go (to suit the cloud). Any modern Windows OS will come with a Access ODBC driver for 32 bit, and you can install the Access Database Engine 2010 for 64 bit and get a 64 bit ODBC driver.

Comment: Thank you Mike, sorry I just use WinSCP to download the access file executing it with an "Execute Process Task". The bat launch only a WinSCP's script.

This week I try the next steps you told me,  I'll tell you how it went.